# How to run sql query in PySpark notebook

Tags: apache-spark-sql, azure-synapse

I have an SQL query which I run in Azure Synapse analytics , to query data from ADLS.
Can I run the same query in Notebook using PySpark in Azure Synapse analytics?

I googled some ways to run sql in notebook, but looks like some modifications to be done to the code to do this.

%%sql or spark.sql("")

Query
SELECT *
FROM OPENROWSET(
BULK 'https://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx.net/datazone/Test/parquet/test.snappy.parquet',
FORMAT = 'PARQUET'
)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the data lake file and write into a dataframe with saveAsTable and query the table as shown below.

```
df = spark.read.load('abfss://<container-name>@<storage-account-name>.dfs.core.windows.net/<filename>', format='parquet')
df.write.mode("overwrite").saveAsTable("testdb.test2")
```

Using %%sql

```
%%sql
select * from testdb.test2
```

Using %%pyspark

```
%%pyspark
df = spark.sql("select * from testdb.test2")
display(df)
```

[image]